read yaml and check for a specific value in jenkins
I have YAML file:
---
accounts:
- account1: compute
  owners: 
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
- account2: storage
  owners: 
  - user4
  - user5
  - user6
- account3 : network
  owners:
  - user4
  - user5
  - user6

I read this Yaml file in jenkins and I need check if account is compute and owner is different then user1, user2, user3 then terminate the pipeline if it match, go to next step.
I tried with if condition but checks only first value.
Thanks in advance.
   def config = readYaml file: "filename.yaml"
   config.accounts.each { sa ->
   sa.owners.each { owner ->
      if (owner != "user1") {
      error('Terminating Pipeline...')
}
}
}


.each{} doesn't work in Jenkins pipelines, because of limitations due to CPS transformation of pipeline code. Use a regular for loop instead.
config.accounts won't work because the keys are numbered. You need to iterate the entries and do a substring comparison.
def config = readYaml file: "filename.yaml"

def validComputeOwners = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

for (account in config.accounts) {
    for (entry in account) {
        if (entry.key.startsWith('account') && entry.value == 'compute') {
            for (owner in account.owners) {
                if (! validComputeOwners.contains(owner)) {
                    error('Terminating Pipeline...')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks a lot. Iteration works fine.
Just how can i get this from yaml file? def validComputeOwners = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'] This values needs come from yaml - thanks again
